# How to add a Matplotlib Graph (Pizza Graph Style) in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I have an Matplotlib Graph with 2 values, and the graph of these values is an "Pizza Graph 2d" i need to place this Graph in my tkinter app, how can i place a Pizza Graph in Tkinter?

I've tried to make a canvas in tkinter and a Figure, but any of these runs, in some part an white frame appear but without the graph, how can i get the graph from the matplotlib in my tkinter aplication?

```py
    matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

    DataBaser.cursor.execute("""
    SELECT RendaMensal FROM Registro
    Where Status = 'On'
    """)

    RendaGet = DataBaser.cursor.fetchone()

    Renda = RendaGet[0]

    print(Renda)

    DataBaser.cursor.execute("""
    SELECT TotalDebt FROM Registro
    Where Status = 'On'
    """)

    TotalDebt = DataBaser.cursor.fetchone()

    Debt = TotalDebt[0]

    print(Debt)

    sizes = [Debt, Renda]

    labels = 'Gastos', 'Renda'

    fig1, axl = plt.subplots()

    colors = ['red', 'green']

    c2 = axl.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%0.0f%%', shadow=False, startangle=90, colors=colors)

    axl.axis('equal')

    circle = axl.axis('equal')

    #plt.xticks(Renda)


    plt.title("Controle do Limite")



    f = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=(100))
    f.add_subplots(fig1, axl)
    f.draw(DataFrame)

    #plt.show()


    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,master=DataFrame)
    canvas.draw()
    #canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating two figures, `fig1`, which you use to plot your pie chart, and `f`, which you use to create the `FigureCanvasTkAgg`. Remove `f` and use `fig1` in `FigureCanvasTkAgg` instead

Something like:

```
fig1, axl = plt.subplots()
c2 = axl.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%0.0f%%', shadow=False, startangle=90, colors=colors)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=DataFrame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand = True)
```

Comment: Thank You so much, this will help me a lot.

Comment: You know how to change the background color of this graph?

Comment: You know how i can update my graph for example i go to another page and when i back (if i make some changes) the graph will be updated